# is it possible to hide number from NSURL tel function in swift 2?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

```
    @IBAction func callingButtonTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    let busPhone = String("0888888")
    let namePhone = String("NAME")
    if let url = NSURL(string: "tel://\(busPhone)") {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url)
    }
```

Hi I'm new at developing apps with Swift. Is it possible when i call this 088888 number from app, number not show up and show 'NAME' instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No this is not possible. The URL-Scheme merely opens the phone app which dials the number.

This is not possible regardless of the programming language on iOS.

Comment: And this is should never be possible, just imagine you are hiding some very expensive pay per minute number with a free number als label. No this is not possible and never should be.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.
These are the capabilities of the tel URL scheme: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/iPhoneURLScheme_Reference/PhoneLinks/PhoneLinks.html
And it has nothing to do with Swift vs Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Always it is not possible to hide the number from URL.We can't hide and show the 'Name' instead of URL No.We can call the no using tel:088888 default using open URL. In iOS it is not possible to do this.

Comment: how bout not hiding the number but still show 'Name' in caller ID? @user3182143

Comment: Go through my answer very clearly.There is no option doing.